# Simple GUI interface and web services for database

Tags: web-services

I've looked around and haven't found just quite what I'm looking for. I help teach a health IT course that often involves doctors and nurses who don't have much experience programming. We are planning to teach students about extending clinical information systems by developing a database and exposing it for queries and use using Web services. This is something which is often done by those with technical experience. We would like to teach students this concept with hands on exercises. However we would like the students to focus more on the concept than coding. Is there a free or open source database program that allows users to create a simple database, develop a simple GUI for their database (for hypothetical data collection), and expose their data using Web services. Mind you, this needs to be simple enough for non-programmers to be able to use with minimal coding experience.

Thank you for your comments and recommendations!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, really broad question, the *database* word doesn't say much about the final task and it's really generic, but I suggest [**Base**](http://www.libreoffice.org/features/base/) from the libreoffice suite or the equivalent counterpart [from openoffice](http://www.openoffice.org/product/base.html) and both are basically the same product if you care about the core features.